# Duplicated rows numbering

Tags: oracle, oracle-analytics

I need to number the rows so that the row number with the same ID is the same. For example:

[image: example]

Oracle database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DENSE_RANK` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS row_number,
       id
FROM   your_table
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( id ) AS
SELECT 86325 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 86325 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 86326 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 86326 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 86352 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 86353 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 86354 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 86354 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ROW_NUMBER | ID |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 86325 |
> | 1 | 86325 |
> | 2 | 86326 |
> | 2 | 86326 |
> | 3 | 86352 |
> | 4 | 86353 |
> | 5 | 86354 |
> | 5 | 86354 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7af85e0e05776a6d2c84e546fa17e5cf)*